# How to add a tooltip to D3.js subplot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently working on trying to create a "facet plot" within d3.js, which I realize in D3 language isn't really a thing. However, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65499073/how-to-create-a-facetplot-in-d3-js) which outlined how to accomplish the task. From this post, I've converted the line chart from vertical to horizontal, and added a few extra padding elements where needed.

Now I would like to add a tooltip to each plot. From working with other pieces of code, this seems quite challenging. For some reason I can't figure out how to attach the tooltip to each individual plot. Any thoughts on how I might be able to accomplish this?

**What it currently looks like:**
[image]

```js
// Data and manipluation:
const data = d3.range(25).map(i => ({
        bib: Math.floor(i / 5) + 1,
        ratio: -1 + Math.random() * 5,
        run: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][i % 5],
        run: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][i % 5],
        name: ['metric1', 'metric2', 'metric3', 'metric4', 'metric5'][Math.floor(i / 5)]
        }));

const grouped = d3.group(data,d=>d.bib);


// Dimensions:
const height = 800;
const width = 700;
const margin = {
       top: 10,
       left: 50,
       right: 50,
       bottom: 50
    }
const padding = 30;
const doublePadding = padding * 2;

const plotHeight = (height-doublePadding)/grouped.size - padding;
const plotWidth = width-padding*2;

// const plotWidth = (width-padding)/grouped.size - padding;
// const plotHeight = height-padding*2;

const svg = d3.select("#chart1")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", margin.left+width+margin.right)
  .attr("height", margin.top+height+margin.bottom+(padding*grouped.size));
  
const g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate("+[margin.left,margin.top]+")");

//Scales:
 const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.run))
   .range([0, plotWidth]);
     
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.ratio))
   .range([plotHeight,0]);
   
// Place plots:
const plots = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(grouped)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
     return "translate("+[padding,i*(doublePadding+plotHeight)+padding]+")";
   })
   
//Optional plot background:
plots.append("rect")
  .attr("width",plotWidth)
  .attr("height",plotHeight)
  .attr("fill","#ddd");
   

// Plot actual data
plots.selectAll(null)
     .data(d=>d[1])
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("r", 4)
     .attr("cy", d=>yScale(d.ratio))
     .attr("cx", d=>xScale(d.run))

// Plot line if needed:
plots.append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return d3.line()
               .x(d=>xScale(d.run))
               .y(d=>yScale(d.ratio))
               (d[1])
   })
   .attr("stroke", "#333")
   .attr("stroke-width", 1)
   .attr("fill","none")
   
// Plot names if needed:
plots.append("text")
  .attr("x", plotWidth/2)
  .attr("y", -10)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d[1][0].name;
  })
  .attr("text-anchor","middle");
   
// Plot axes     
 plots.append("g")
   .attr("transform","translate("+[0,plotHeight]+")")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(4));

 plots.append("g")
   .attr("transform","translate("+[-padding,0]+")")
   .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Load d3.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.6.1/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="graph-container">
    <div id="chart1"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

See a solution in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/d4xmbosf/):

Add a **g** element with background and text(s):

```
const tooltip = d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
  .style('visibility', 'hidden');
  
tooltip.append('rect')  
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 50)
  .style('fill', '#fff')
  .style('stroke', '#000')
  
tooltip.append('text')
  .attr('x', 20)
  .attr('y', 20)
```

Update it on **mouseenter**, **mousevove**, **mouseleave**:

```
plots.append("rect")
  .attr("width",plotWidth)
  .attr("height",plotHeight)
  .attr("fill","#ddd")
  .on("mouseenter", (e, d) => {
    tooltip.style('visibility', 'visible');
    tooltip.select('text').text(d[0]);  
  })
  .on("mouseleave", () => tooltip.style('visibility', 'hidden'))
  .on("mousemove", e => tooltip.attr('transform', `translate(${e.clientX},${e.clientY})`))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael! I've started working through the code and I can at least see the tooltip, so that is a great start! However, there's a few things I'm still struggling with.

1. The tooltip seems to be set to hover over the entire chart, not a particular data point. How do I make the tooltip only appear over points?

2. I'm sure I can figure this out, but once 1 is complete, I then have to change the tooltip to include data for that particular point.

3.  The tooltip is off-place right now. How do I align it positionally with either my cursor or a data point?

Comment: Actually, I'm really only focused on question 1. The rest will come after I figure out 1. Thanks for your help Michael!