# How to create a grouped histogram plot in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a grouped histogram in d3.js based on some fake data. I have managed to create the three histograms but they all look the same. See image.[image: See image]. I want the histogram to display the data for each "ski academy" in the dataset, so that the upper show the data for academy A, the middle for academy B and the bottom for academy C. I understand how I can achieve this for circles (scatterplot) based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65499073/how-to-create-a-facetplot-in-d3-js) but I don't understand how I can implement this logic with d3's histogram() method. Can someone please help me?¨

Here is my code:
index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>D3.JS </title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
const dimensions = {
    width: window.innerWidth * 0.8,
    height: 1000,
    margin: {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 20
    },
    groups: 6,
    padding: 20
}

dimensions.boundWidth = dimensions.width - dimensions.margin.left - dimensions.margin.right
dimensions.boundHeight = dimensions.height - dimensions.margin.top - dimensions.margin.bottom

dimensions.plotWidth = dimensions.boundWidth - (dimensions.padding*2)
dimensions.plotheight = (dimensions.boundHeight / dimensions.groups) - dimensions.padding


const render = async () => {
     // data generator function
    const datasetGenerator = () => {
        const dataset = []
        for(let i=0; i < 15; i++) {
            const obj = {
                bib: [1,2, 3][Math.floor(i / 5)],
                run: [1,2, 3][Math.floor(i / 5)],
                skiacademy: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'][Math.floor(i / 5)],
                test: ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'][Math.floor(i / 5)],
                performance: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)
    
            }
            dataset.push(obj)
        }
        return dataset
    }
    // 1. data
    let data = datasetGenerator()
    console.log(data)

    // 2. Accessor function
    const xAccessor = d => d.performance
    const yAccessor = d => d.length

    // 3. group data on skigymnasium

    const datagrouped = d3.groups(data, d=>d.skiacademy)

    // 4. Scales, axis and bingenerator
    const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                  .domain([0, d3.max(data, xAccessor)])
                  .range([0, dimensions.plotWidth])
                  .nice()

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                  .scale(xScale)
                  .ticks(6)
                  .tickPadding(10)

    //      Here I use the d3.histogram() generator but as you see on the next line I am not passing it the grouped data because that doesn`t work
    const binGenerator = d3.histogram().domain(xScale.domain()).value(xAccessor).thresholds(20)

    const bins = binGenerator(data)
    console.log(bins)

    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                  .domain([0, d3.max(bins, yAccessor)])
                  .range([dimensions.plotheight, 0])
                  .nice()

    const svg = d3.selectAll("#wrapper")
                  .append("svg")
                  .attr("height", dimensions.height)
                  .attr("width", dimensions.width)

    const bounds = svg.append("g")
                  .attr("transform", `translate(${dimensions.margin.left}, ${dimensions.margin.top})`)

    const plot = bounds.selectAll(null)
                  .data(datagrouped)
                  .join("g")
                  .attr("transform", (d, i) => {
                    return "translate("+[dimensions.padding, i*(dimensions.padding+dimensions.plotheight)+dimensions.padding]+")";
                  })

    plot.append("g").call(xAxis).attr("transform","translate("+[0,dimensions.plotheight]+")")

    const binGroup = plot.selectAll(null).data(d => d[0]).join("g")


    const binGroups = binGroup.selectAll("g").data(bins).join("g")
    
    const barPadding = 1

    const barRects = binGroups.append("rect")
     .attr("x", d => xScale(d.x0) + barPadding / 2)
     .attr("y", d => yScale(yAccessor(d)))
     .attr("width", d => d3.max([0, xScale(d.x1) - xScale(d.x0) - barPadding]))
     .attr("height", d => dimensions.plotheight- yScale(yAccessor(d)))
}



render()
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial-and-error, I found a solution that works. The problem is that d3.bin creates a new object where the grouped information is lost. So my solution was to add an array with the binned information to each group in the dataset, like this:

```
    const bin = d3.bin().value(d => d.performance)

   // datagroup
    const binneddata = bin(data, d=>d.performance)

    datagrouped.forEach((d, i) => {
        d[2] = bin(datagrouped[i][1])
        return d

    })
```

[image: test]